# Как сверстать блоки плиткой?

Tags: css

Есть несколько div-блоков:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Как сверстать блоки, чтобы они встали таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блоки могут быть произвольной высоты, в зависимости от контента. Если применять к блокам свойство *float: left*, то нижние блоки выравниваются по нижней границе самого высокого блока в первом ряду.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/ , http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Тут, по идее, в сторону flex нужно смотреть.

Comment: Этот вопрос уже задавался: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603095/media-box-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-flex/603354#603354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2 (с использованием скриптов):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flexboxes').masonry({
    itemSelector: 'div' // обращаемся к пунктам
  });
});
```

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  width: 630px;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Использую второй вариант. Почему-то отказывается работать правильно, если для элемента (3n-1) задавать margin: 0 15px 20px 15px.

Comment: Также если всем блокам задать ширину, например 310px, а блокам (3n-1) - 330px, то также не работает. Переносится но новую строку третий блок.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а что за ширина `(3n-1) - 330px` ?

Comment: Центральные блоки .flexboxes > div:nth-child:(3n-1) {margin: 0 15px 20px 0;} . Просто ширина контейнера - 960px. Ширина блока - 310px. И центральные блоки должны быть с отступами от крайних в 15px слева и справа.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, нужно поиграться со стилями. Я не знаю всей картины, по этому не могу судить

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mONqag - тут у меня блоки не переходят на другую строку, но друг на друга налаживаются.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов, укажите в скрипте `percentPosition: true` и поиграйтесь со стилями своими

Comment: Разобрался. За отступы по бокам отвечает свойство gutter.

Answer (score 1):

Столбцами?

```
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  margin-right: .3333%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/psmhwqq7/

Comment: Столбцами сверстать проблем нет. Вёрстка адаптивная, и при меньшем разрешении третий блок переходит во второй ряд, а два последних - на третий. Поэтому столбцы не подходят.